# Change image src url using HttpResponse in Django views

Tags: python, django, nginx

Is there any way of redirecting an image's 'request' URL in Django views, to an Nginx server so that Django doesn't have to serve the image itself? The background to my questions has to do with image tracking, which for obvious reasons requires a trip to Django.

For example, I have a webpage with an image, say;

`<img src="https://mydjangoserver.com/uuid/image-url/image.jpg">`

Which is passed to views which strips the UUID and src url for the image is changed to the NGINX server, say,

```
https://my-nginx-server.com/image.jpg
```

The image is then loaded within the **original** html page that first requested the image.

Any advice on how to redirect the image src url to avoid it being served by Django would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer as it turns out was simple:

```
def image_redirect(request, image):
    return redirect(f'https://my-nginx-server.com/{image}')
```

Thank you @Tim Schilling [better-simple.com](http://better-simple.com) for your help.